# what is the useful of "META-INF/spring.provides"

Tags: spring-boot

i saw the most of spring-boot-starters contain "META-INF/spring.provides", I want to know what is the meaning of this file.

such as [mybatis/spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/mybatis/spring-boot-starter/blob/master/mybatis-spring-boot-starter/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.provides)

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1926

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found the answer from [github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12435)